# mod_wsgi multiple processes lead to active deleted lock files

Tags: linux, apache, mod-wsgi

I used mod_wsgi lib(version: 4.2.5-1.1) to generated an API server with multiple processes so that the API server could provide load balancing, here's the wsgi configurations beblow:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
ServerName localhost
WSGIPythonPath /opt/cloud/services/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:8777>
    WSGIDaemonProcess test-api user=openstack group=openstack processes=3 threads=2 maximum-requests=5000 shutdown-timeout=30
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/app.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup test-api
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    ErrorLog /var/log/test-apache24.log
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /var/www/test>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LimitRequestLine 80000
    LimitRequestFieldSize 80000
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
        SSLCipherSuite E****************************************
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/xxxxxxx/server-cert/test.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/xxxxxx/server-cert/test_server.key
        SSLVerifyDepth 10
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
Listen   196.128.8.72:8777
```

After this configure I got an expected API server daemon and sub daemons like:

```
root      6344     1  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
opensta+  6345  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
opensta+  6348  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
opensta+  6350  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun    6351  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun    6355  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun    6357  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun    6361  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun    6364  6344  0 14:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
wwwrun   32172  6344  0 14:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/apache2cei/httpd.conf
```

The API server works as well but I found that these daemons created some unreasonable lock files which status was deleted with linux lsof tools:

```
:~ # lsof | grep deleted

httpd      6344            root    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6345       openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6345  6378 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6345  6379 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6345  6380 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6345  6381 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6348       openstack    9wW     REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6348  6382 openstack    9wW     REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6348  6384 openstack    9wW     REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6348  6385 openstack    9wW     REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6348  6386 openstack    9wW     REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6350       openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6350  6389 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6350  6390 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6350  6391 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6350  6392 openstack    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6351          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6355          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6357          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6361          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd      6364          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
httpd     32172          wwwrun    9w      REG               0,18         0 1937090182 /run/wsgi.6344.0.1.lock (deleted)
```

we can see these lock files was used by these API daemons through the process ID in the last column.

These deleted lock files disappeared when I change processes num to 1 in the wsgi conf file as:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess test-api user=openstack group=openstack processes=1 threads=2 maximum-requests=5000 shutdown-timeout=30
```

So does anyone have any ideas with this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are wanting to know. What is "unreasonable" meant to mean? Are these lock files causing you problems? The lock file is a cross process mutex lock designed to ensure that only one process in a daemon process group can accept a connection at a time. It is in part to avoid thundering heard problems.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Hi, Thanks for your reply, these lock files do not trigger any problems. What make me confused was the status of these locked files,  they are "deleted", and when I ran my OS system health check script, these deleted files was founded. So the status of these files are supposed to be "deleted"?

Comment: Deleted in this context means that it was deleted from the file system, but some process may still have a reference to it. If your application is forking sub commands out of the web process which hang around beyond the next restart of Apache HTTPD server, this can occur. The very long ``shutdown-timeout`` you run with, which is recommended at 5 seconds and usually never changed, might in certain circumstances see this happening if for some reason something is stopping the web application processes from shutting down properly.

Comment: Usually those processes would be forced killed by Apache after 5 seconds, which is why there is no point increasing the ``shutdown-timeout``. Why are you changing the value of it?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton We change the value of `shutdown-timeout` due to extend the waiting time to avoid a forced killing even if there are still active requests. As you said, the value I run with is too long, so I changed it to 5 on my env, but the locked files still exits.

Comment: Making it longer than 5 will not help for an Apache shutdown or restart, even when graceful as Apache only allows 5 seconds before it kills them. The mod_wsgi daemon process don't act like normal Apache child worker processes during graceful shutdown or restart. Apache doesn't provide any other way of having them managed.

Comment: As to the lock files, if really concerned, you should check parent/child process relationships and determine whether they really are mod_wsgi daemon processes, or processes forked from them. Also check the process state to see whether they might be marked as zombies or stuck on network file operations.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The deleted lock files was just created by the mod_wsgi daemon processes and its sub processes, you can check the describe in my question above. The daemons was working well and deleted lock files was exits at the same time. These files vanished after I stopped mod_wsgi daemons.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton In addition, I use `lsof -p $pid` to stat one mod_wsgi daemon which intend to find out all the file relevant to lock, and I got two lock files: `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_lock.so` and `/run/wsgi.7981.0.1.lock (deleted)`, maybe only the first one was the correct one?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The number `7981` in `/run/wsgi.7981.0.1.lock (deleted)` is the pid of mod_wsgi daemon.

Comment: The files would vanish upon the next Apache restart, or shutdown, but they shouldn't show as deleted during that time. Look in the ``/run`` directory and they should still be visible during that time. The reason they didn't show up when ``processes=1`` is that you don't have multiple processes that need to cooperate together so don't need them. The way your original description was, it sort of suggested they hung around after Apache was restarted or shutdown. If they don't then all is fine.

Comment: So if ``lsof`` shows them as deleted even when they are visible in ``/run``, there is something funny about ``lsof``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton As you said, it's funny about `lsof`, these lock files was just visible in `/run`, and the same time they are deleted status by `lsof`. So maybe all of this about mod_wsgi is just normal , thanks for your patient explanation :)